# Rework display of reviewers list for "controversial" suggested edits in moderator tools lists

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, moderator-tools

I was looking through the `/suggested-edits` page and saw the "Controversial" tab so I checked it out to see what it was.  I figured I'd see edits that had at least one accept and one reject vote, and the tooltip verified that assumption (grammar error and all!) as seen in the screenshot.  However, when I scanned the list, I didn't see any separation between those who accepted and those who rejected.

In this screenshot:
[image]

It *looks* like it has three approvers, when in reality serg rejected that edit:
[image]

I propose either splitting the description in the listing to mirror the one that's shown at the bottom of the second screenshot, or perhaps something as simple as using `<s>` on the ones who were overridden.

Choice 1:

> approved by **Approver Guy**, **Other Approver**
>
> rejected by **Mean Rejector**

> rejected by **Mean Rejector**, **Beauty School Reject**
>
> approved by **Approver Guy**

Choice 2:

> approved by **Approver Guy**, <s>**Mean Rejector**</s>, **Other Approver**

> rejected by **Mean Rejector**, **Beauty School Reject**, <s>**Approver Guy**</s>