# Does Stack Exchange crawl websites?

Tags: discussion, broken-link, link-validator

I'm seeing the user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; stackexchangebot/1.0; +http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130398)` in my web server logs.

Why is Stack Exchange crawling my site?

Where do I report any issues?

Comment: Stack Exchange cares about links. Awesome. Now removing `rel=nofollow` would be the next logical step (since that obviously destroys linking as far as search engines are concerned).

Comment: @konrad that was done [a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable)

Comment: @Jeff Oh, never mind me then. Move along. Kudos on the fine-graned approach though, I’m guessing the technical details aren’t exactly trivial.

Comment: Wait a second. The number 130398 hasn't been changed since the question was posted. So you timed it perfectly so that this would be post #130398, and *then* set up the bot to link to this question?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, that's what we call the "[grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grace-period?sort=faq)".

Answer (score 104):

Stack Exchange runs a bot that validates all the external links in our network of sites. This bot performs `HEAD` requests in a heavily throttled way. This bot was created to combat **link rot** in our network.

Links are tested once every 3 months.

If you notice any issues with this bot please email `team@stackexchange.com`

---

The proposed operational mechanism (this is not final as of April 26, 2012) is:

> all being planned at the moment, in a nutshell, community will add a "special comment" to the post asking the creator to fix it, it will also add it to a list in /review and we will remove one of the tabs ... also we will add a couple of badges to help drive the fixing

namely:

- Adds a comment to the post asking the author to fix it:

  [image: "We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)"]
- Adds the post (question or answer) to a special list on the /review tab

Comment: not fully deployed yet, in initial planning phases at the moment

Comment: What does it do when it finds a dead link?  Is it flagged at least?  It would be awesome if posts with dead links appeared in the review page (or 10k).

Comment: @JeffMercado all being planned at the moment, in a nutshell, community will add a "special comment" to the post asking the creator to fix it, it will also add it to a list in /review and we will remove one of the tabs ... also we will add a couple of badges to help drive the fixing

Comment: More stinking badgers? W00t!

Comment: I hope there will be badges for fixing link in your own posts, and that the auto added comment will be auto removed once the link has been fixed.   It may be worth only adding items to the review tab, if the author has not fixed the link themselves within n days, also should the review tab only show posts with lots of views that have broken links, so the most important post are fixed first?

Comment: I see answers only referring to external links all the time. This is something that should be fighted more vigorously on the moderation side. But this addition is also welcome!

Comment: @UncleZeiv How are moderators supposed to fight it?  We aren't given any information on this except when users point out where there's link rot, in which case, we go and address it.

Comment: Can you make this flag / remove known URL shorteners since this pretty much kills the existing "too expensive" argument.

Comment: @AviD actually you can sometimes find the important content, I saved a linkrot post thanks to the Wayback MAchine the other day.

Comment: @waffles So I should deliberately add a dead link, wait 3 months and then edit it to get the badge? ;)

Comment: @yoda I think a better approach is to add a good link, then launch a DDOS on the target site, take it down, forever, then replace the link with a link to the wayback machine. AND PROFIT. I hear botnets can be rented for quite cheap these days.

Comment: @awoodland I do not really intend to walk through comments though, the content I care about most here is post bodies

Comment: Curious: are you also doing this for images? And *if* adding @awoodland's URL shorteners, then maybe personal storage such as Dropbox and the like could get some attention too. (Especially for images, I feel.) (Nice, by he way!)

Comment: @waffles: No one cares about comments anyway. ;) But if you *really* could this implement for URL-Shorteners and posts alone, I'll declare you King Waffles! ... Would be an awesome name for a restaurant chain, too.

Comment: @casperOne: sorry, my bad, by "moderation side" I meant the part of the community the cares about the site, not "official" moderators alone. Plus I'm not saying that the problem is link *rot*, but irresponsible linking without extracting or rephrasing information. I'm seeing lots of answers that only contain links, especially on StackExchange sites. I guess we need to educate new communities more on this point?

Comment: @unclezeiv flag link only answers as not an answer as appropriate

Comment: If someone else adds a link, will that user be notified about dead links (too)? (In either case, the possibility of the links going bad is another reason to discourage Wikipedia [links to well-known terminology](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44405/for-well-known-terminology-how-useful-is-adding-links-to-wikipedia), I'd say.)

Comment: @waffles - noticed it working [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90863/rework-display-of-reviewers-list-for-controversial-suggested-edits-in-moderato#comment366561_90863) - does that cause a question bump?

Comment: Is this still active? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/broken-links is no more and Google only [finds some hits on Meta](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22We+detected+an+invalid+link+in+your+post%2C+please+correct+it.+(this+message+will+be+automatically+removed+when+the+link+is+fixed)%22).

Comment: @casperOne: any idea if this is still implemented?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'm not sure, but I'll check.

Comment: @TimPost Is this [tag:status-completed] ? (The bot)

Comment: @AshRj Should actually be `[faq]` - I'll fix it up proper and put it in on Monday.

Comment: @TimPost I have to ask, which Monday ? ;)

Comment: @TimPost FYI on the wayback solution I just posted, I always disliked nagging users about this; now we don't have to (as much).

Answer (score 33):

The Wayback Machine now has an availability API

http://archive.org/about/wayback_api.php

It might make sense to incorporate this into the crawl. If we can't find the original source link in the crawl, ask Wayback if they have a copy of said link, and if they do **we can fix the post ourselves without bugging users about it**.

The crawl is of course still necessary to check the validity of the link. But we have a much better fallback that can save everyone a lot of work, and reduce load on the human-powered queues. Robot work is always preferable to human work..

Comment: Oh, now that's cool!

Comment: This is awesome. Many users fix broken links by replacing them with a link to the Wayback copy since it's the simplest thing to do, hooray for robots! Sticking this on our feature agenda.

Comment: This is going to the devs sometime today to look into implementing. It should fix the immediate problem, provided that the wayback copy is the same age or newer than the post when the link was made, and we only automatically re-write them after several failed checks. There will be a unique PostHistory entry when this happens, so we can conceivably find / improve these posts if they too heavily depend on the now fixed link (but later, another project, another time). Hopefully nothing will get in the way of it working.

Comment: @TimPost any updates?

Comment: @JeffAtwood It went on the core call, but there's a bit of resistance.  The Wayback API gives us everything we need to know in order to responsibly re-write the link (e.g. we're not linking to a version much older than what the author was originally linking to that never updated) - but the Community user would be making a _ton_ of edits. Even though I specified a PostHistory event for Community fixing a link so these could be reviewed if needed, we'd need to better address the 'if needed' before this could go in. (1/2)

Comment: The other concern was that this would (at least in part) prevent posts that depended too heavily on a link from being surfaced and fixed to be fundamentally better posts, I don't entirely agree with that. Anyway, it's all leading back to finally getting the link review queue in shape to actually be used, at which time I'll propose this again in the context of actually having that in place - where we put the 'fixed' posts in front of people for edits to make them fundamentally better as is possible. (2/2)

Comment: @TimPost an alternative would be something like the IA [404 handler](https://blog.archive.org/2013/10/24/web-archive-404-handler-for-webmasters/) but on SE's side. As you rewrite the Amazon links *in the output*, you may rewrite certain links to go to a handler which checks for the existence of the target or redirects to archive.org.