# Crawling the chat transcripts

Tags: support, chat

I want to make a usable chat search and in order to do this I want to gather the chat messages from SO.

AFAIK chat is not in the data dump nor is it available through the API. So I want to crawl the chat transcripts for messages.

As a test I will start with the transcript of [room 11](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11) by starting at the present and working my way back to the first message. Once I have done that (and everything is ok) I will only need to crawl for updates instead of the entire thing.

Currently the transcript contains 1209 days * 5 time frames == 6045 pages. I want to crawl pages with 10 seconds interval (throttling) to get all messages within a single day.

I found [this 2 years old meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135727/crawling-stack-overflow-instead-of-the-dumps-for-fresher-data-in-our-search-resu) about the same thing and I am wondering:

- whether that still applies
- whether you SO people are fine with me crawling the pages with above interval
- whether I can expect problems (i.e. unexpected throttling from your side)

Comment: Related/how to get just the transcript events: [Obtaining full chat transcripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129374/obtaining-full-chat-transcripts)