# An easy way to download chat transcriptions?

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

I am not an engineer, a developer or a computer programmer.

And I do not understand how the following solutions work.

1. [Crawling the chat transcripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219813/crawling-the-chat-transcripts)
2. [Obtaining full chat transcripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129374/obtaining-full-chat-transcripts)

It is possible to copy and paste but the results are–unsatisfactory–and quite confusing to follow. As I am computer illiterate, I have to resort to taking several screenshots when the conversation is several days old and the transcription larger than the size of my monitor. Then I end up with cropping the images. Is there a more efficient way?

Please help.

**Details**
I have a MacBook Pro laptop, OS is X Yosemite, version 10.10.5, and my preferred browser is Chrome, version 87.0.4280.88. I do not have Firefox installed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1545/discussion-on-question-by-mari-lou-a-an-easy-way-to-download-chat-transcriptions).

Comment: What happened to your question about twitter? I think it started with "What are the ways to..." ?

Comment: @user1271772 I don't have a Twitter account perhaps you 're thinking of someone else.

Comment: Didn't you ask a question like "What are the ways to get SE to listen to us?" when it turned out that they responded immediately to a Twitter post?

Comment: No, don't think so: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A223820+twitter

Comment: It was this one! https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317011/391772 You were an answerer, rather than the questioner.

Comment: The link you posted shows the answer with -4  :/

Comment: I was not one of the people to downvote it!

Comment: @user1271772 must have left a mark if you still remember It! :)

Comment: It was when I first started using Meta.SE, and when I first became a regular on the SE network. My first question on MSE was heavily downvoted and was inappropriately closed as a duplicate of a question that I had already posted a link to in my question (so the closer should have known that I already saw that older question).