# I've run across a lot of broken links lately, what should I do?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, 404-not-found

Perhaps I'm just crazy.. but in the last few days I've experienced a noticeable increase in the number of links to what seem like promising SO answers from a few years back, but ultimately end in the wonderful 404 page.  I don't know if I've just encountered an unusual spree of URL typos, or if old [bad] content is being pruned.

Has anyone else noticed this?  Further, is there a method for reporting bad links in or to older answers?

<sub>I am talking about broken links **on** Stack Overflow **to** other SO questions.</sub>

Comment: SE is working on a broken link detector.

Comment: Links **on** Stack Overflow or links **to** Stack Overflow?

Comment: Links **on** SO **to** other SO questions.

Comment: You can comment to ask the poster to update the link. Additionally, if it is a link-only answer (or comment), you could flag it as NaA (or obsolete). If you are able to find the content some other way, you could update the link yourself

Comment: It's not entirely impossible that the links point to deleted questions/answers. Then it would take you to the 404 page unless you have 10k+ rep. Have you one or two examples of the dead links you came across?

Comment: @DanielFischer Here's one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature?tab=votes&page=1  I'll see if I can find a few of the other ones.

Comment: Yup, deleted on 22nd February.

Comment: How practical would it be to have a system that, when and answer is deleted, also removes or detects links to the question in other SO posts and notifies the author that their link is now broken?  This seems like the catch22 of deleting old popular answers solely for the purpose of keeping the site slim -- it may break hundreds of other answers that reference the deleted one.

Comment: Here's a crazy idea: maybe if so many people weren't *obsessed* with deleting everything they got near, those links would still have worked... Just a thought. The way things are going, this problem is only going to get worse. Much worse

Comment: I'm with @jalf on this one.... users have gotten too delete-happy in their attempts to make SO "pure" and purging all the questions they don't think meet a specific set of guidelines. A lot contain good content that has been linked to in many places, and its a shame to throw away user contribution by deleting questions just because they don't meet a few peoples view of the perfect Q&A site.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, if the answer is any good and the link is being used to provide *useful* supporting material, I've been checking to see if the dead page is in The Wayback Machine. If it is then I replace with the WBM link.

Comment: I do the same, but it gets old pretty quick doing it manually. Hmmm....that sparks an idea...

Answer (score 3):

There was a link validator in development ([see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130398/does-stack-exchange-crawl-websites), and [link-validator](/questions/tagged/link-validator)), but I don't believe it's live yet.

Unless this tool gets released, there's no way to report broken links.

Of course, as everyone can edit anything on Stack Overflow, feel free to edit the post to correct the link if at all possible. If it's unclear where the link *should* be pointing, it might be worth commenting on the post in question and notifiying the author, in the hope they might fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can search for what the name of the answer appears to be given the URL and fix it.

Comment: Hmmm not sure if the link validator checks SE network links for 404s or not. The time-of-post validation doesn't check for 404 from SE, I know that much

Answer (score 0):

I have a modest proposal that may help alleviate broken links:

Add the ability to search for the link on the Wayback Machine. This would allow users a second chance to get to the link if it's broken.

I figure a small dropdown menu next to links might do the trick. Clicking the original link takes you to the original url, while the dropdown allows you to search Wayback or even report a dead link.