# Do the close votes disappear if the duplicate question reference is deleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I voted to close the following question because the OP posted the exact question couple of days ago before posting this question. I remember that because I edited the original question with formatting. OP copied the edited question and posted a new question with couple of changes on the title. Below given question was posted only yesterday (*February 17, 2013*).

[How to convert the date values field on flat file as header columns within SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921302/how-to-convert-the-date-values-field-on-flat-file-as-header-columns-within-ssis)

I am sure that the question that I used for the duplicate reference had 1 answer. The answer did not have any upvotes though.

#### What I noticed:

- The question used for duplicate reference has been deleted. I don't know who deleted the question (whether OP or moderator).
- Close votes (there were two votes) on the above mentioned question have disappeared.

#### Searches on Meta:

Below Meta post shows that when someone can delete their own question.

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Below Meta post shows when a close vote will disappear.

[What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today)

#### Questions:

1. Did the OP delete the original question because it had only one answer with no upvotes?

   *My understanding*: The Meta searches show that only questions with multiple answers cannot be deleted even none of them had up votes. I assume that OP can delete the question since there was only one answer with no upvotes.
2. Did the close votes disappear from the above-mentioned questions because the question used for duplicate reference was deleted?

   *My understanding*: The Meta searches show the close votes will disappear only if there were at least 100 views or the last close vote had elapsed 4 days. In this case, the above-mentioned question has only 29 views as of writing this post and the question itself was posted only yesterday. These conditions do not meet the criteria to expire the close votes.

#### Update: (17:45 UTC)

I just noticed that when I click Close link, I get the below message but there are no close votes count displayed on next to the link. I don't find anything on the revision history of the question that suggests a moderator modified something.

Is this behavior because a user is allowed to close a question only once and I already voted to close this question?

[image: Close]

Comment: I just want to point out that if a user is deleting their questions and re-posting them to get more attention they are likely going to be question banned rather soon as having deleted questions counts strongly against you.  If you want you can flag one of the posts though, as a mod may choose to take some action against this inappropriate behavior.  That discussion is rather independent of how to handle close votes on a deleted question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166606/duplicate-dialog-breaks-when-the-identified-duplicate-is-deleted/166899#166899):

> When a question is deleted, we'll see if any existing close-as-dupe votes point to it as the original. If so, the votes will be removed.

As with normal close-vote removal, the votes are soft-deleted, so they still count when checking to see if you've already voted.

Comment: I) What happens when the original question is deleted by the poster, then undeleted? Are the soft-deleted close votes on the newer one (the duplicate) restored in that case? If not that seems like a bug, because it means anyone can simply delete and undelete their older question to remove all close votes on their newer duplicate one. The people who voted to close the newer one cannot even re-vote in that case, even if they're aware that their votes have been deleted.

Comment: II) A related question of mine can be found [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9431/workaround-to-get-rid-of-all-close-flags), if you can kindly take a look. In this case the original was untouched, but the poster deleted and undeleted the newer voted-as-duplicate question. This too simply caused all close votes to disappear. This case is even worse because the original wasn't deleted, so the ability to remove all close votes from a question just by deleting and undeleting it seems like a clear bug.