# Vanishing close-votes when the original version of a duplicate is deleted?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, gaming-the-system

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795152/how-to-display-html-tags-in-text-area-with-javascript-or-jqurey) as a duplicate of [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793234/how-to-display-html-tags-in-text-area-with-javascript-or-jqurey) (now deleted, after being closed as off-topic and voted down to -6), so did one other user. The author of both questions deleted the earlier one, and now the later question has gone from two close votes to zero. This makes a certain amount of sense (it's no longer a duplicate), but I can't cast another vote even though my original vote is gone. This is troubling for a few reasons:

- The original post was closed as off-topic; I can no longer cast a close vote against the new post as off-topic, even though it's a duplicate of an off-topic question (my close vote is effectively lost)
- Users can abuse this to swallow a certain number of close votes while spamming the same question into the system (as has just unintentionally happened with the above two questions)

Is this a feature or a bug? Was my close vote supposed to vanish, and afterwards am I supposed to be unable to cast a second close vote for the next-best reason?

Comment: Does the system automatically remove close votes if the post considered to be the original (and therefore being duplicated) gets deleted?

Comment: @Preom This is what I seem to have experienced, yes.

Comment: Answer is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168083/152859). Better turn  this into feature request asking to change this behavior, at least if the question is deleted by its own author.