# Deleting and undeleting the target of a self-duplicate resets close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, undelete

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308527/unable-to-send-email-in-mobiles-in-c-sharp-unity3d) which was a direct duplicate of [another one by the same author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306913/sending-email-with-mobile-device-in-unity3d).

So I cleaned up the original and voted to close the duplicate. Unfortunately, he then proceeded to delete the question I just cleaned up. Annoyed, I told him he shouldn't have done that. And as a result he seems to have undeleted the original.

Now it does seem that the close votes have been reset. Either that, or I no longer have an indicator that the question currently has a close vote. Trying to vote once again shows me I can't do so because I already voted on the question.

Is this expected behaviour? Or are we dealing with a bug here?

Comment: Wait... Bart and @Cody aren't you duplicates of each other??? ;)

Comment: I've tried closing him as such @ShaWizDowArd. But he just deletes and undeletes himself....

Comment: Oh my... I see possible rip in the Space-Time Continuum!

Comment: OK, back to topic: the votes are reset indeed, but it's the same behavior as delete votes being reset if OP deletes his own post then undelete. So if it's a bug, it's affecting more than just close votes.

Comment: Ah dammit, this is the same issue it seems: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189911/vanishing-close-votes-when-the-original-version-of-a-duplicate-is-deleted?rq=1

Comment: Yup - you can add your new example there to bump it, or just start a bounty. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Vote to close this one as a dupe please. Then at least the info is around. I'll throw a bounty on the other one.

Comment: If I were a mod I would most likely delete that other question just to see the counter here reset! :-P

Comment: Hmm, it appears that [this is by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168083/153008). I do not agree with that design.