# Self-deletion+undeletion clears NAA/VLQ flags

Tags: bug, flags, undelete

A user whose post was flagged as not-an-answer can remove all those flags by deleting his post and undeleting it right afterwards. This happens because those flags are (rightfully) cleared when the post is deleted. However, when the post is undeleted by the user without any edits I think any Community-cleared flags should be reactivated (or a new flag raised instead) to avoid someone from cheating this way to prevent his post from showing up in the history.

[image: post history]

Comment: I was under the impression that a user cannot undelete a self-deleted post unless they have edited it.

Comment: At least that post was never edited.

Comment: Seems to be the same/a similar issue as this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193807/deleting-and-undeleting-the-target-of-a-self-duplicate-resets-close-votes

Comment: Doesn’t it also clear spam/offensive flags? That’s probably pretty bad too.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that was changed recently - at least I saw spam flags for already-deleted posts in the queue.

Comment: I would rather see the original flags restored, rather than new ones created.  If there's a decently long flag queue it can result in someone continually bumping their posts to the "end" of the flag queue by continual deletion/undeletion.

Comment: @Oded now you're an SE developer maybe you could check into this further? It certainly seems possible at the moment and I recently asked a duplicate question which is why I put a bounty on this one.

Comment: Just experienced this issue on stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360618/user-deleted-undeleted-post-which-caused-queue-to-invalidate