# Remove Close Votes as duplicate of older questions when duplicate is deleted

Tags: feature-request, bug, review, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I have this https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/113801 to review in the Close Votes queue. The question has 3 Close Votes as duplicate to a question that is deleted.

Should the Close Votes as duplicate not be removed (maybe after some time) when the other question is deleted? **Update:** It seems that the functionaly has been [implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166606/duplicate-dialog-breaks-when-the-identified-duplicate-is-deleted), but the fix only applies to newly deleted question, so that older question (Close Votes) are not taken into account.

Also the hint message displayed when i the select the deleted question is not correct. The message is **"This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"**. I think it should say that the question is deleted and cannot be selected.

> [image]

<sub>Note similar question: [Duplicate dialog breaks when the identified duplicate is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166606/duplicate-dialog-breaks-when-the-identified-duplicate-is-deleted), but the question in case is about one year old, while the "dialog breaks" post is from this year. So removing close votes is only applied to deleted question when the fix was rolled out.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate dialog breaks when the identified duplicate is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166606/duplicate-dialog-breaks-when-the-identified-duplicate-is-deleted)

Comment: @hims056 the question in case is about one year old, while the dup you specify is from this year. So removing close votes is only applied to deleted question when the fix was rolled out.

Comment: That's still a dupe, your request was implemented.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ok you got me. I have changed my title and updated some information. Maybe it is now more diffrent.