# User Notification of expiring hyperlinks?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, link-rot

Would it be possible to implement feature whereby a user is notified of a hyperlink becoming unavailable? In doing so, they can take the action of fixing the link or removing the reference altogether? Surely if a 404 error is received on a page for over a week, then the link can be presumed dead?

If this is going to far (for a single user), how about creating a review queue for expired hyperlinks?

Comment: It's in the works currently as a new review queue, and there's already a bot that goes round and comments.... finding the duplicates... or not.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130398/152859).