# Culture and language specific links in tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, markdown-preview, culture

This is not a huge issue, but something I found when reviewing [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4300574) (ensure you have `markdown` selected). I noticed that one of the links pointed to the [French version of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9dthzd08%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) for doco about the Regexp object in JavaScript. (Note that this was already there, it wasn't a problem with that suggested edit).

Wherever possible Stack Overflow is intended to be English oriented. Can we warn users when they input a link that has an obvious culture component to it? This is a simple mistake for an editor to make, and very simple for reviewers to overlook - however it could easily be detected with a regex either during the edit or at the time of submission.

A simple warning (rather than a blocking validation) should be sufficient - there is nothing wrong with a non English culture link especially if the author mentions that the target isn't in English (there will also be many occasions where there is no English version of the target page). I imagine something like this would be fine - although the color may need to change.

[image]

Comment: So for popular sites you want to have a regex test based on implementation details of that other site that triggers a blocking error at stackoverflow? Wouldn't it be better to leave a comment if someone stumbles upon such link and have the author fix that? If this get implemented it could be part of the dead-link checker. as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130398/does-stack-exchange-crawl-websites)

Comment: Rene raised a good point. I'll add that if this gets implemented, it should not be about *culture* but about *language*. For instance, "It appears you have entered a link to a resource which is not in English. [etc.]"

Comment: @rene Ummm, no. If you check the URL for the MSDN example I had in the question you will see a language/culture of `fr-fr` is specified. This is what I am talking about - it is a relatively common standard and easily regex'd. And I specifically said a warning, not a validation error. Stumbling across it isn't really the best option - that's exactly what we have at the moment.

Comment: @Louis I don't really care what the message is. You are right that it's predominately about language, however the pattern I'm looking to detect is always as a language/culture pair. For example `fr` in a URL could be anything, whereas `fr-fr` will likely always be french-french.